# Removing a test (unapproved) app from iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've downloaded a project from GitHub in order to test its Game Center implementation. So, I've created an app with explicit ID and registered it in the iTunesConnect in order to enable Game Center feature (and to add a Leaderboard). Anyways, after I've finished with testing, I want to remove the app from because, obviously, I don't want to submit it to the store, but I can't find a "delete" button to remove it.

This can be found in docs :

> Apps that have not been approved yet can’t be deleted; instead, reject
>   the app.

But I am not sure if this applies to my situation, and how to reject the app ? And is there any other way to remove unwanted apps (which are added  just for testing purposes) from the iTunesConnect MyApps list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per latest changes in iTunesConnect, it's not possible to delete application in iTunesConnect if app not approved.